# Selecting Rows based on multiple related tables

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```
modifiers = db.Table('modifiers',
    db.Column('modifier', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modifier.id')),
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id')),
    )

modified_ingredients = db.Table('modified_ingredients',
    db.Column('recipe', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id')),
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id'))
    )

class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(256))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    directions = db.Column(db.Text)
    prep_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cook_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    image = db.Column(db.LargeBinary())
    ingredients = db.relationship('ModifiedIngredient', secondary=modified_ingredients)

class Ingredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredient'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)
    mod_ing = db.relationship("ModifiedIngredient")

class Modifier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modifier'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)

class ModifiedIngredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modified_ingredient'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    unit = db.Column(db.String(20))
    ingredient = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredient.id'))
    modifiers = db.relationship('Modifier', secondary=modifiers,
        backref=db.backref('modifiers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

I'm trying to retrieve recipes based on having two or more ingredients.

I'm able to retreive recipes that have single ingredients with the following:

```
db.session.query(models.Recipe).join(models.ModifiedIngredient, models.Recipe.ingredients).join(models.Ingredient).filter(models.Ingredient.name == 'garlic')
```

However, adding multiple filters return 0 results. This makes sense, it's matching a single ingredient to a recipe, and an ingredient can't be both garlic and onion. So, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is to use an intersect.

Issue multiple queries with each of your filter options:

```
q1 = db.session.query(models.Recipe).join(models.ModifiedIngredient, models.Recipe.ingredients).join(models.Ingredient).filter(models.Ingredient.name == 'garlic')

q2 = db.session.query(models.Recipe).join(models.ModifiedIngredient, models.Recipe.ingredients).join(models.Ingredient).filter(models.Ingredient.name == 'onion')

q3 = q1.intersect(q2)
```

And q3 will have all items that have both 'onion' and 'garlic'